# How would you handle a situation where the OP keeps asking for more?

Tags: discussion, questions

So [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32997572/want-the-horizontal-bar-to-graph-the-bars-from-high-to-low) post started off, from what it seems, someone asking for help to plot a histogram. It was odd that they asked to plot it from high to low.

Their original code had what seemed to be an attempt to count the number of occurrences, so I tried to give them an example of how to plot it and how to use the [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html). This is all mainly because their original code didn't have complete information.

Since it wasn't what they were asking for exactly, as they posted a comment, I requested they provide their full code. What's more is that they began asking for stuff outside their original question.

Now some might address the original one and tell them to ask a new question for the other stuff, but one of the reasons I contribute to SO is that it becomes a *learning experience* as well. I truly have learned a lot from being on this site about [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas), and [matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matplotlib), to list a few.

Further down in the comments, the OP, to me at least, began to sound rude and kept asking for even more. At that point I decided to tell them that it needs to be addressed separately and they should ask a new question.

**My question**

For future reference, how would you guys handle it? Where would you have said *enough is enough*? Am I wrong for going as far as I did?

Comment: In the very first comment, "I could email it you if you provide me with your email address" sets off alarm bells already. I'd say you handled that very diplomatically by asking for a MCVE in reply.

Comment: Downvote, leave comment asking for missing information. move on. Answering with missing information is a waste of time for both you and the OP.

Comment: Help until you don't feel like helping anymore. If you feel that it's a net positive for yourself, keep going. As you said, you have no obligation to do any of it.