# Recently Deleted posts in moderator tools misses some questions

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, 10k-tools

About 4 hours ago, [a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317565/the-mobile-view-of-the-front-page-looks-weird) was deleted by its author.
[image]

However, the question is not included in the ["Recently Deleted" posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last2days) in the moderator tools:

[image]

As we can see in the image above, we have deletions before and after the question, but the specific question is not included.

To me this looks like a bug in the moderator tools view. IMO it should include *all* deleted posts.

Comment: Are any self-deleted posts shown in that list?

Comment: @TZHX: No, they aren't.

Comment: @BoltClock That's what I thought based on looking on the site I can see it on. Seems likely it's a deliberate design decision rather than a bug.

Comment: Bah, I hate it when my edit effort goes to waste ...

Comment: @TZHX: Why in your opinion would it be desirable? The list is there for monitoring incorrect or abusive deletions, and in general, this can include deletions by the author of a post.

Comment: Maybe the number of self-deletions completely dwarfs all other cases, and SO decided that the majority of these were rightly people cleaning up their own mess?

Comment: I don't claim to believe it is desirable, btw, just that it looks likely to be deliberate. The above comment is just a guess.

Comment: @TZHX: Yes I guess it could make sense depending on the numbers. Ideally there would be a filtering mechanism, but that's another discussion.

Comment: Hey, didn't we recently hear about [a questionable self-deletion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317470/what-can-i-do-if-a-user-removes-a-question-after-ive-written-an-extended-answer)?  I can't see why this should be deliberately hidden.

Comment: Seems to have been a deliberate change for performance reasons: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92979/restore-the-10k-ability-to-see-all-closed-deleted-posts-in-a-list/93037#93037 (and click through the link in that answer).